# Create exe install with bat file, folders, sub folders

Tags: batch-file, exe

I have this file tree:

[image]

`install.bat` is a batch script which creates a file tree on the computer, copies content of the folders "jar" and "sql" into `C:/`, to install jre and mysql.

I would like create an executable ".exe" which contains the folder "jar", "jre", "mysql_server", "sql", the file "install_mysql.bat" and launch the "install.bat".

I tried using the software "Bat To Exe Converter", but it doesn't work when I try to include folders and sub-folders.

Comment: Might be able to do it with [Iexpress](http://mintywhite.com/software-reviews/maintenance-software/iexpress-convert-batfiles-exefiles-howto/). I think this may be off topic for SO.

Comment: You will need to research how to create an installer. Doing this research for you is not within the scope of this site.

Comment: IExpress has the same problem that "Bat To Exe Converter", I don't add folder but only files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a winrar SFX file(self extracting archive).